# magento : Your password reset link has expired

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an issue when I click on the reset password link url :

I have four website in one magento platform  like : domain.com, domain.com/us/
domain.com/it/ domain.com/ca/

On my main site (domain.com) when I click on forgot password I get the email with reset password link . When I click on the reset password link I am successfully redirected to reset password url .

But when I follow same process with my other sites like domain.com/us , I am getting the forgot password email but when I click on the reset password link I am redirect on the Forgot password link (domain.com/us/customer/account/forgotpassword/) instead of reset password link and I am getting an error message stating "Your password reset link has expired".

Comment: Are you actually using multiple store views or multiple websites?

Answer (score 2):

Customers are shared either per website, either across all websites, so at least, a customer account is usable on all of the store views that a website contains. Consequently, it is normal that the password reset link works for your store views.

In fact, if you would like to separate the customer accounts between your store views, you would have to create separate websites that would not share customers.